# Encrypted backups on a NFS or SSHFS share

Tags: backup, encryption, nfs, ecryptfs

Been going around in square circles here so any help and/or suggestions welcome!

Goal:

- encrypt my backup data on shared network server (shared via NFS or SSHFS)
- want the encrypted folder to be transparent to my local machine, i.e work as a normal mounted NFS or SSHFS folder would.

  - This is so that I can keep using "backintime" as a backup tool. It does everything I need except encryption.
- The encrypted folder should be mounted automatically on login. E.g. same as encrypted private directory.

  - For unattended backups

Some notes

- My home directory is already encrypted, but I don't just want to copy over the encrypted files because then I won't have any useful version'ing on them.
- Tried to use encfs and also Cryptkeeper. Using local folders works fine but when trying to set-up the encrypted folder on the NFS share it fails.
- Running Ubuntu Lucid, 10.04
- I'd like to set this up on all clients on the local network to backup to the same local networked server which is also running Lucid 10.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but I do want to clearly note that [eCryptfs](http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs) (the encryption technology used by your Encrypted Home Directory) will *not* work properly on top of NFS or Samba for the reasons detailed in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/277578).

You could, however, easily backup the encrypted data that you find in `/home/.ecryptfs` using [rsync](http://manpg.es/rsync) or backintime, or any other automated backup utility.